# помогите решить задачу по JS (

Tags: javascript

Дано натуральное число. Установить, является ли последовательность его цифр при просмотре их слева направо упорядоченной по возрастанию. Например, для числа 1478 ответ положительный, для чисел 1782 и 1668 — отрицательный и т. п.

Comment: Приложите вашу попытку

Comment: Очень просто - создаёшь список чисел с упорядоченными цифрами и проверяешь наличие данного числа в нем.

Answer (score 4):

```
number
  .toString()
  .split('')
  .every((digit, i, digits) => i == 0 || digits[i-1] < digit)
```

`i == 0` - первая цифра пропускается
`digits[i-1] < digit` - остальные цифры больше предыдущих

Answer (score 4):

```
x=>x==[...`${x}`].sort().join``
```

Проверка:

```js
f=x=>x==[...`${x}`].sort().join``

console.log(f(0))
console.log(f(128))
console.log(f(10))
console.log(f(88))
console.log(f(87))
```

Comment: `join\`\`` что это за хитрость такая?

Comment: Спец.синтаксис для codegolf =)

Comment: @entithat, [tagged string](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B) и немного шаманства)